# how to display validation message in specific <div> element in Struts2

Tags: struts2

I'm new to Struts 2 and facing this problem in keeping the layout of my page:

```
<s:form action="abc.action"><br>
    <s:textfield key="name" label="Name" /><%--here I need to display errormessage for `name`--%>
    <br>
    <s:textfield key="email" label="Email" /><%--here I need to display errormessage for `email`--%>
    <br>
    <s:submit>
</s:form>
```

I'm using xml-validator for my action class, this works fine. but the validation-error messages appear over the fieldname and text-box. but i want it to come afterwards respective text-box (inside another html-container). Kindly advise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're used to writing HTML, switch to the simple theme.

In struts.xml is probably the best place:

```
<struts>
  <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />
</struts>
```

Then just use the *fielderror* tag to put the error for the field where you want it.

It's a good to be familiar with the Struts2 tags: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/tag-reference.html

Comment: Thanks Quaternion , this is fine as I want to customize my form with styles rather than the in-built tables provided by struts. Things has become really simple now !

Comment: Great, if this has resolved the issue click on the check box for this answer.  Then we'll know this issue is closed.

Comment: You can also put `struts.ui.theme = simple` in `struts.properties`.

Comment: some like it but all the properties can be put in struts.xml, using the constant tag, if conventions are used the struts.xml stays rather thin, so it can do double duty, one less place to look for things.

Answer (score 4):

That is the default according to Struts2 default templating.  To change it, see http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/working-with-struts-2-theme-template/

Comment: Thanks nmc , i'll try changing the theme also in my next assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You Can also Use **Struts2 validation Framework**

Validation framework comes with set of useful routines to handle form validation automatically and it can handle both **server side** as well as **client side** form validation. If certain validation is not present, you can create your own validation logic by implementing java interface.

```
com.opensymphony.xwork2.Validator
```

Validator uses XML configuration files to determine which validation routines should be installed and how they should be applied for a given application. validators.xml file contains all common validators declaration. If validators.xml file is not present in classpath, a default validation file is loaded from path

```
com/opensymphony/xwork2/validator/validators/default.xml
```

Validators Scope
There are two types of Validators in Struts2 Validation Framework.

1. Field Validators
2. Non-field validators

**Field validators**, as the name indicate, act on single fields accessible through an action. A validator, in contrast, is more generic and can do validations in the full action context, involving more than one field (or even no field at all) in validation rule. Most validations can be defined on per field basis. This should be preferred over non-field validation wherever possible, as field validator messages are bound to the related field and will be presented next to the corresponding input element in the respecting view.

```
<validators>
  <field name="bar">
      <field-validator type="required">
          <message>You must enter a value for bar.</message>
      </field-validator>
  </field>
</validators>
```

**Non-field validators** only add action level messages. Non-field validators are mostly domain specific and therefore offer custom implementations. The most important standard non-field validator provided by XWork is ExpressionValidator.

```
<validators>
      <validator type="expression">
            <param name="expression">foo lt bar</param>
            <message>Foo must be greater than Bar.</message>
      </validator>
</validators>
```

For whole detail example visit this link [link to struts2 validation](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/struts2-validation-framework-tutorial-example/)